# Changing UITabBarItem's selected Tint Color in iOS 10

Tags: swift2, ios10

I can't seem to change the tint color for selected UITabBarItem in iOS 10. It was working perfectly in iOS 9. I'm using Swift 2.x and have tried using self.tabBar.tintColor programmatically, and runtime attributes in storyboard as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this;

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], forState:.Selected)
```

Thanks